# How to define a new RPN operator with \pstVerb to convert pt to the active unit?

Tags: pstricks

I want to do a vector addition with different units as follows,

```
(1+2pt,3+4pt) % of course this point format will not work for the current PSTricks
```

My solution is to write the point in PostScript notation. However a problem occurs: I need a new operator to convert `pt` to the active unit.

The operation I want to do in PostScript looks like the following,

```
(!1 2 Pt2AU add 3 4 Pt2AU add)
```

And how to define `Pt2AU`?

Note that the default active unit in PSTricks is 1 centimeter. But we can change it.

The MWE you can use is given as follows,

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor

\pstVerb{/Pt2AU {72.27 div 2.54 mul} bind def}% needs correction to accommodate all possible active unit
\psset{unit=1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \psline(1,3)(!1 2 Pt2AU add 3 4 Pt2AU add)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might look inside `pstricks.pro` and `pst-eucl.pro` to find cool tricks for manipulating PostScripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this: (I think this version works).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-eucl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\pstVerb{ /aceGetXcoor {GetNode 0 mul add} bind def
          /aceGetYcoor {GetNode exch 0 mul add} bind def
        }
\newcommand{\mynewnode}[4]{%
    %% #1 = old node
    %% #2 = addition to x-value
    %% #3 = addition to y-value
    %% #4 = new node name
    \pnode( !   tx@EcldDict begin
                /N@#1 aceGetYcoor \expandafter\pst@number\dimexpr #3\relax\space add 
                /N@#1 aceGetXcoor \expandafter\pst@number\dimexpr #2\relax\space add 
                \pst@number\psxunit div exch 
                \pst@number\psyunit div
                end
            ){#4}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=2cm,yunit=20pt}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,0)(5,5)
    \pnode(2,3){A}
    \mynewnode{A}{2cm}{1cm}{B}
    \mynewnode{B}{-1in}{10pt}{C}
    \mynewnode{C}{2em-2ex}{-20ex}{D}
    \psline(A)(B)(C)(D)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This example uses the PostScript library from `pst-eucl`.  It looks like, if you approach it this way (since LaTeX converts all units to pts), that you can pass any unit you like through the parameters `#2` and `#3` to get the point placed where you want.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the important parts of the A.Ellett's answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=10pt}% must be declare before \pstVerb!

\makeatletter
\pstVerb
{
    /pt2xu {\pst@number\psxunit div} bind def
    /pt2yu {\pst@number\psyunit div} bind def
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \psline(1,3)(!1 3 pt2xu add 3 10 pt2yu add)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{yunit=10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
  \pcline[YnodesepB=-3pt,offsetB=10pt](1,3)(1,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{yunit=10pt}

\def\myLine(#1)(#2){\rput(#1){\psline(#2)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
  \myLine(1,3)(3pt,10pt)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```